# allowedFileTypes is deprecated

Tags: objective-c, macos

In macOS 11.0, the `NSOpenPanel`'s [allowedFileTypes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nssavepanel/1534419-allowedfiletypes?language=objc) property is marked as deprecated in favor of the [allowedContentType](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nssavepanel/3566857-allowedcontenttypes?language=objc) property.

We're developing a plug-in to a third-party macOS app. The plug-in asks user to provide a licence file - we provide the file with our proprietary `abcLicence` file extension. As we cannot handle double clicks as a plug-in, we rely on `NSOpenPanel` triggered from the plug-in UI. Because there were close to no benefit registering the file type as we cannot respond on shell file actions, we are not including it in the plug-ins `plist` file. The plug-in supports macOS 10.12+.

```
NSOpenPanel *openDialog = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];
openDialog.title = @"Locate ABC license file";
openDialog.allowedFileTypes = @[@"abcLicence"];
```

How to update the code to use the new API if available while keeping supporting macOS 10.12+?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the delegate method [`panel:shouldEnableURL:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsopensavepaneldelegate/1535200-panel?language=objc), available since 10.6. With this method you can implement arbitrary logic to decide if an item should be enabled and hence selectable, in your case you can just check the extension. HTH

Comment: It appears that this only works for OpenPanels; is there an equivalent for SavePanels?

Comment: @Bernard – This wouldn't make sense for save panels, it is about controlling what existing files can be selected for *reading*. In a save panel the user enters a name for a new, i.e. non-existent, file to *write* (and the save panel handles the name matching an existing file with an overwrite warning dialog). You should ask a new question explaining what you trying to do and where you are stuck and someone will undoubtedly help you out.